# FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING is stripping the < character and any text after it

Tags: php

I have a strange problem when using `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` on a variable (populated by human input). It seems to strip the `<` character and any text that comes after that. The `>` character is left untouched.

I assume it thinks the `<` is an HTML tag that needs to be stripped, however there is no closing tag behind it, so I haven't got a clue why it would behave like that. Is there a way to make it leave the `<` in place, and still sanitize the way it should?

Comment: That's what it does, http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php To avoid this result, don't use it.

Comment: What do you *want* it to do?

Comment: I want it to sanitize the string by removing html/php tags, etc. Which worked fine until someone reported to me that the < character and everything behind it is removed, even it it was something like: "Blabla < this is other text", which would result in "Blabla ".

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The root issue is that when you use `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` to strip HTML tags you are handling your input as HTML. According to your description, your input is plain text. As such, the filter can only corrupt the input data, as users have already reported.

While it seems to be quite a popular technique, I've never understood the concept of striping HTML tags on plain text as sanitization method. If it isn't HTML you don't need to care about HTML tags, for the same reason that you don't need to care about SQL keywords or command line commands. It's nothing but data.

But, of course, when you inject your string into HTML afterwards you need to escape it in order to ensure that:

1. Your data is displayed as-is
2. The result is still valid HTML

That's why [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) exists. Similarly, you need to use the corresponding escape mechanism when you dynamically generate any other kind of code: SQL, JavaScript, JSON...

Comment: You have a point there. I was trying to safeguard my application against attacks, but i assume it would be safe enough to skip the FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING (or strip_tags()) completely, and simply use htmlspecialchars() at the very end before adding it to the database, which i was already doing. That will also htmlencode the php open/close tags.

Comment: I would not apply `htmlspecialchars()` before storing data. That makes it more difficult to use it for anything else that displaying it in a web site. I'd store the original raw data and transform it when actually using it. The overload of on-demand escaping is hardly noticeable.