# validation if filter_input returns false

Tags: php, validation, filter-input

The documentation for `filter_input()` mentions :

> Value of the requested variable on success, FALSE if the filter fails,
>   or NULL if the variable_name variable is not set.

After studying the various examples online, I was surprised to see that none of them (that I know of at least) checked for the value `FALSE`. Most of the examples only checked for the `NULL` value :

```
if ( is_null( filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) ) ) {
   // display error
}
```

Is there a reason for this ? Or is there a real life example that does check for the `FALSE` value ? If so, would you kindly provide the example so that I may benefit from it.

Also, would you kindly provide the circumstances in which the filter_input could possibly fail. Much appreciated.

Comment: *"I was asking about the reason why most people did not check for the FALSE value when dealing with filter_input."* - People are just strange animals at times, we don't know why some do and some don't.

Comment: Thank you for the humour, but coming back to my question... do you have any examples where `FALSE` is being check for ? Secondly, under which circumstances is `filter_input` likely to fail ?

Comment: That was 50% humour and 50% seriousness (*nice to see you have a sense of humour*) ;) I couldn't give you an example as to where FALSE is being checked. Have a look at the following Q&A on Stack; I think it may *hopefully* answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/q/23392128/ - **Edit:** Why it would most likely fail I would say/think that it would depend on the filter options that are set.

Comment: Just as the link given below http://www.sitepoint.com/input-validation-using-filter-functions/ states - *"The main pitfall is that the functions are only as good as the filter you apply to it."* So, as per my edited comment above, I was right (wink). Hopefully we have answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is because !0 is true. Why? By adding the ! you are doing a boolean check, so your variable gets converted. And according to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php):

When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:

```
the boolean FALSE itself

the integer 0 (zero)

the float 0.0 (zero)

the empty string, and the string "0"
```

So the integer 0 gets converted to false while all other integers are converted to true.

This is why you need to do a type safe check for false or null as these are the values `filter_input()` returns if it fails for some reason

```
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if ($name === false) {
    //filter failed
}
if ($name === null) {
    //variable was not set
}
```

Comment: i have no ans your question but please visit the following link i will   help you. http://www.sitepoint.com/input-validation-using-filter-functions/