# PDO filter _input not working in php form processing

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i have a form with `input type="text"`

- so to get protection of my SQL i used the `filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'title', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);`
- ETC to filter my input

### ERROR

- it doesn't filter anything bellow is the SQL store data
  [image]

i don't know what's wrong 
 here is the full code

```
<?php
$db_username = "sanoj";
$db_password = "123456";
try {
#connection 
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=localtest', $db_username, $db_password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$data = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO test (type, title, model, modelnumber, prode, price, location, descrption, youare, name, email, phone, ipnu) VALUES (:type, :title, :model, :modelnumber, :prode, :price, :location, :descrption, :youare, :name, :email, :phone, :ipnu)');
$type = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'type', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$title = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'title', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$ufile = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'ufile', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$ufile1 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'title1', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$ufile2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'title2', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$ufile3 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'title3', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$ufile4 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'title4', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$model = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'model', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$modelnumber = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'modelnumber', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$prode = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'prode', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$price = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'price', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$location = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'location', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$descrption = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'descrption', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$youare = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'youare', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$phone = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'phone', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$ipnu = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REMOTE_ADDR', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$data->execute(array(':type' => $type, ':title' => $title, ':model' => $model,     ':modelnumber' => $modelnumber, ':prode' => $prode, ':price' => $price, ':location' =>     $location, ':descrption' => $descrption, ':youare' => $youare, ':name' => $name, ':email'     => $email, ':phone' => $phone, ':ipnu' => $ipnu));
#exception handiling
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
echo "$ipnu";
?>
```

these code were working fine but now its not working

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392128/what-does-filter-sanitize-string-do

Comment: @walther check the image in question i does't filter

Comment: How did you expect the sanitisation to take place?

Comment: @Ja͢ck when user input value is & then it should become this  &#38;  this how it worked but now i don't know what happened now it process directly to SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ampersand doesn't get encoded by default using the FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, so you need to add that in the flags:

```
$title = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'title', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
```

Comment: hey thanks it works but i used the above code it did the same and now it does't whats the wrong

Comment: @sanoj The `FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP` is definitely necessary to convert the ampersand; what's not working?

Comment: its working i asked about my code which is mentioned in question

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean; the code in your question didn't have the flag and my answer does :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $text);
```

So you would only have letters and numbers.

Comment: no that wont work when you copy and paste filter charter it will be placed inside text box