# PHP check if input field is not empty and if this have special characters

Tags: php, string, validation, special-characters

I want to check if an input field is not empty and if he has special characters. I tried this:

```
function stringValidator($field) {   

    if(!empty($field) && (!filter_var($field, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)))
    {

            return "You typed $field: please don't use special characters 
            '<' '>' '_' '/' etc.";

    } }
```

The PHP not even tried to validate this way.
Any tips?

Comment: [This is not how FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23392684/965834) (it's badly documented though, to be fair).

Answer (score 0):

A `preg_match()` call will work nicely.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/si9KO))

```
function stringValidator($field) {   
    if(!empty($field) && preg_match('~[^a-z\d]~i', $field)) {
            return "You typed $field: please don't use special characters '<' '>' '_' '/' etc.";
    }
    return "valid";  // empty or valid
}

$strings = ["hello", "what_the"];
foreach ($strings as $string) {
    echo "$string: " , stringValidator($string) , "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
hello: valid
what_the: You typed what_the: please don't use special characters 
            '<' '>' '_' '/' etc.
```

---

Or a `ctype_` call:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/XTFgJ))

```
function stringValidator($field) {   
    if(!empty($field) && !ctype_alnum($field)) {
            return "You typed $field: please use only alphanumeric characters";
    }
    return "valid";  // empty or valid
}

$strings = ["hello", "what_the"];
foreach ($strings as $string) {
    echo "$string: " , stringValidator($string) , "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
hello: valid
what_the: You typed what_the: please use only alphanumeric characters
```

Comment: @PhilipeDeSouzaSantos  Have I solved your issue? Any feedback for me?