# PHP - FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED does`t work correctly

Tags: php

First I want to know what is FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED default flag?

and when I try:

```
filter_var('α', FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);
```

'α' ascii is 224 when I use  `FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW` it should encode ascii values less than 32. but when I put 224 ascii character it get encoded.

(edit) I want to not encode the ascii characters above 127 but it returns '%CE%B1'

Comment: Specify what is the expected output and what you got

Comment: 244 in what encoding? in UTF-8 it's decimal 206177 and in CP-437 it's decimal 224 and in Windows-1253 it's decimal  225. if you mean CP-437 then be specific about it

Comment: You should use high instead of low it’s not respected from w3 in this site, but they explains very well to me see here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/filter-sanitize-encoded-constant-in-php

Comment: @hanshenrik sorry I mean 224. in acsii table 224 is 'α' character.

Comment: ASCII goes from 0 to 127. There's no 224. :-?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález It's from the extended ASCII table. And based on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23392684/8068675 My guess is; it doesn't support the extended ASCII table.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález when you say "extended ASCII table", what encoding are you talking about? OP is saying "α" is 224, and in the CP-437 encoding, that is true, "α" is 224 in CP-437

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158241/php-replace-umlauts-with-closest-7-bit-ascii-equivalent-in-an-utf-8-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure i understand exactly what you want, but.. does this work?

```php
function encode(string $str): string
{
    $ret = "";
    for ($i = 0, $max = strlen($str); $i < $max; ++ $i) {
    if (ord($str[$i]) > 127) {
            $ret .= $str[$i];
        } else {
            $ret .= urlencode($str[$i]);
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

it urlencodes all characters except those with uint8-values above 127, which are left untouched.. is that what you want?

edit: another possibility, if you're talking about CP-437, you want to urlencode every character *except* characters above 127 in CP-437? in which case,

```
function urlencode_cp437(string $str): string
{
    $ret = "";
    for ($i = 0, $max = strlen($str); $i < $max; ++ $i) {
        if (ord($str[$i]) > 127 && mb_check_encoding($str[$i], 'CP-437')) {
            $ret .= $str[$i];
        } else {
            $ret .= urlencode($str[$i]);
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

- i guess? (untested, but should work, i guess?)
- should probably use [mb_ord()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ord.php) instead of ord(), but since CP-427 is a single-byte ascii-compatible encoding, and mb_ord doesn't exist until php 7.2, i guess ord() would work regardless, idk